# excel copy cell value to new sheet if column a = "x"

Tags: vba, excel

How can I copy cell values of column `G` to another sheet if column `A` = "X" ?

I am wanting those values to keep the drop down list up to date when I add or remove any X's. The drop down list currently updates dynamically based on contents from sheet 2.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will copy column "G" cell values from 'Sheet1' to 'Sheet2' if the value in the column "A" cell on the same row contains "X".

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyGCellVals()
  Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
  Dim i as Integer, lastRow As Integer, sht2Row As Integer

  sht2Row = 1
  Set sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Set sht2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
  With sht1
    lastRow=.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i=1 to lastRow
      If .Cells(i,"A")="X" Then
         sht2.Cells(sht2Row,"G") = .Cells(i,"G")
         sht2Row = sht2Row + 1
      End If
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Matt, see if this works

```
Dim sheetOrigin As Worksheet
sheetOrigin = Worksheets("Name of your origin worksheet")
Dim sheetDestination as worksheet
sheetDestination = worksheets("Name of your destination worksheet")
dim columnA as range
Set columnA = Range("A:A")
dim columnG as range
Set columnG = Range("G:G")
Dim cell as Range

For Each cell In columnA
 If cell.Value = "X" Then
  sheetOrigin.columnG.Select
  Selection.Copy
  sheetDestination.columnA.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
 End If
Next cell
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment with less than 50 reputation so unfortunately it will appear as an "answer" I guess.

The answer by Amorpheuses is awesome but my question is so similar that I wanted to add to this conversation. OP only needed to copy from one sheet to another. My issue is as follows;

***I have a total of 13 sheets ("Master", and then sheets of "MCL01", "MCL02", "MCL03", etc all the way to "MCL12"). I need to copy each row that is classified via a dropdown list to its respective sheet.**

**For example, if a row of data is classified as "MCL01", I need that row to be copied to sheet "MCL01", and if a row of data is classified as "MCL07" I need that row to be copied to sheet "MCL07" etc etc.***

Based on the code already written in the answer from Amorpheuses above, how many integer variables do I need?